# Create an 'at' job in a script

Tags: ruby, dynamic, system, cron-task

In Ruby, I need to have a script queue up some `at` jobs. Making system calls is easy enough, I can use backticks, `system`, or `%x()`. But the `at` command is necessarily multi-line, and requires the command input `ctrl+d` to terminate. How can I create an `at` job dynamically?

Example (Ruby):

```
`at #{time}\nrun_other_script.rb\n:q`
```

Effect:

```
at 2014-10-14 11:30
at> run_other_script.rb
at> <EOT>
```

But of course my example doesn't work. What does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`at` accepts input from standard input.

Using [`IO::popen`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-popen) with `w` mode, you can send  input to subprocess:

```
IO.popen("at #{time}", "w") { |f|
  f.puts "run_other_script.rb"
}
```

You can also use [`open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) module.

Comment: Would I need to send a dedicated cancel command, or would it assume it at the end of the `popen` block?

Comment: @DevonParsons, Do you mean EOF? You don't need to do it. If you want to do it explicit,  you can call `f.close`

Comment: EOF will be automatically sent once the block exits because Ruby will close the connection to the child, but, as @falsetru says, using `f.close` will do it also, and it makes it more obvious what is happening. You can rely on the built-in behavior, or you can be more explicit but redundant.